# Simultaneous whistles and clicks?

Tags: whistles, cetacean, echolocation-clicks

Does anybody know if cetaceans can produce simultaneous click and whistle sounds?

In case they can't, if a recording shows simultaneous clicks and whistle sound can we infer that there are, at least, 2 cetaceans present?

All the best

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most toothed whales (with the exception of sperm whales) have two sound generators - a pair of phonic lips in the left and right nasal passages - that they can activate independently. For whistling delphinids, that indeed allows them to produce simultaneous clicks and whistles, and also allows some species such as pilot whales to produce biphonic calls with two independent fundamental frequency contours.

Here are a few references for more information
https://journals.biologists.com/jeb/article/218/24/3987/14345/On-doing-two-things-at-once-dolphin-brain-and-nose

https://journals.biologists.com/jeb/article/216/21/4091/11699/Nasal-sound-production-in-echolocating-delphinids